# How to assign $scope variable in data-target

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Bootstrap and AngularJS. I have some requirements in my project where I have to assign a `$scope` variable to `data-target`. Something like this:

```
<data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emp.id">
<div class="modal fade" id="emp.id" role="dialog">
```

Where `emp` is an object which I am getting from backend and the `id` is its attribute. When I am clicking on the button nothing is happening. Why?

Answer (score 1):

typically you don't need data-target in angular.. you can toggle sections by using ng-if ng-hide ng-show..

but i guess you can always use something like :

```
data-target="{{\'#\'+emp.id}}"
```

Comment: and for id it should be like id="{{emp.id}}" ? @MayK

Comment: Please share your code in a jsfiddle and i'll fix it : )